# Ranking stats with respect to num. of events

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, ranking

I was looking for a different way to rank scores stats for basketball player,

let say player no. 1 have stats of 1/1 (one throw ,one success)

and player no. 2 have 9/10 (9 sucess out of 10 throws)
I want player no. 2 will be ranking higher.

All I can think of is define a threshold for number of throws and then rank it by regular success percentage.

thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

Given that we would like to score the performance of the player, and not predict his future success (is this really the case?)

I would suggest the following; given that the player stats is $\frac{x}{y}$, $w(x) \cdot x - y$ where $w(x)$ is the number of points added for each good shot (*e.g.,* $w(x)=1$ when it's a free-throw, $w(x)=2$ when it's a regular shot, and $w(x)=3$ when it's a three-pointer.)